# Duplicate removal functions keeping the first occurence

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I use the following functions to remove duplicate while maintaining  the first occurrence and without changing the order.

```
    def uniqueList(row):
    words = str(row).split(" ")
    unique = words[0]
    for w in words:
        if w.lower() not in unique.lower():
            unique = unique + " " + w
    return unique
df["value_corrected"] = df["value_corrected"].apply(uniqueList)

"""   1   """
sentences = df["value_corrected"] .to_list()
for s in sentences:
    s_split = s.split(' ')  # keep original sentence split by ' '
    s_split_without_comma = [i.strip(',') for i in s_split]
    # method 1: re
    compare_words = re.split(' |-', s)
    # method 2: itertools
    compare_words = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([i.split('-') for i in s_split]))
    # method 3: DIY
    compare_words = []
    for i in s_split:
        compare_words += i.split('-')

    # strip ','
    compare_words_without_comma = [i.strip(',') for i in compare_words]

    # start to compare
    need_removed_index = []
    for word in compare_words_without_comma:
        matched_indexes = []
        for idx, w in enumerate(s_split_without_comma):
            if word.lower() in w.lower().split('-'):
                matched_indexes.append(idx)
        if len(matched_indexes) > 1:  # has_duplicates
            need_removed_index += matched_indexes[1:]
    need_removed_index = list(set(need_removed_index))

    # keep remain and join with ' '
    print(" ".join([i for idx, i in enumerate(s_split) if idx not in need_removed_index]))
    # print(sentences)

print(sentences)
```

For most of the cases it works excepting:

1. removes prepositions also since it's applied to the entire content of a row, there needs a condition I believe for the function to be applied on words with len >3
2. sometimes removes " ' "
3. does not eliminate duplicate when word is in lower and upper also, example: 'apple' vs 'APPLE'

Data sample:

```
data = {'Name': ["LOVABLE Lovable Period Panties Slip da Ciclo Mestruale Flusso Medio (Pacco da 2) Donna', 'Laessig LÄSSIG Set di Cucchiaio per bambini 4 pezzi Uni menta/mirtillo",
             "Béaba BÉABA, Set di 6 Contenitori per la Pappa per Svezzamento Bebè in Silicone",
             "L´Occitane L'OCCITANE - CREMA MANI NUTRIENTE AL BURRO DI KARITÈ PER PELLI SECCHE 150ML"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Desired output:

```
LOVABLE Period Panties Slip da Ciclo Mestruale Flusso Medio (Pacco da 2) Donna
Laessig Set di Cucchiaio per bambini 4 pezzi Uni menta/mirtillo
Béaba, Set di 6 Contenitori per la Pappa per Svezzamento Bebè in Silicone
L´Occitane - CREMA MANI NUTRIENTE AL BURRO DI KARITÈ PER PELLI SECCHE 150ML
```

Is there a way I can modify the above functions to cover this situations also?

Thank you so  much.

Comment: In pandas the method you're interested in is `DataFrame.duplicated()`, which will return a boolean series marking duplicated rows except for the first occurence (this dehavior can be changed with the `keep` parameter).
See more info here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

Comment: @Erlinska, thank you but if I understood correctly your answer,  I try to remove duplicates on each row and not duplicate rows

Comment: Could you give an example of an input dataframe and the expected output?

Comment: As above.  I think it would be better to add to the question given these 10-15 sentences/strings (put in a lot of different scenarios) I need to output them as <show expected formatting>.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the strings provided...

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd
import re
# import unidecode

data = {'Name': ["LOVABLE Lovable Period Panties Slip da Ciclo Mestruale Flusso Medio (Pacco da 2) Donna", 
                 "Laessig LÄSSIG Set di Cucchiaio per bambini 4 pezzi Uni menta/mirtillo",
             "Béaba BÉABA, Set di 6 Contenitori per la Pappa per Svezzamento Bebè in Silicone",
             "L´Occitane L'OCCITANE - CREMA MANI NUTRIENTE AL BURRO DI KARITÈ PER PELLI SECCHE 150ML"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def dedupString(s):
    '''
    Given a string 's' it processes the string and returns a string with duplicated words removed.
    - replaces acute accent with single quote
    - split string inc. punctuation to list
    - sets 'ALL CAPS' words to 'All Caps' words (only during processing)
    - loops through list and removes duplicates
    - if word has a uppercase in the third char (like L'Oréal) reinstates that
    - deduplicates the list and returns the list joined with a " "
    '''

    #replace acute accent (´) with a single quote (')
    s = s.replace("´", "'")
    #split the string inc. punctuation.  If ticks and dashes etc. go missing from the output
    #add them to the end of the second square brackets below.  Example -> [.,!?;-HERE]
    l = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;-]", s)
    output = []
    seen = set()
    #loop through the words
    for word in l:
        wordAllCaps = False
        #if word is all caps record it
        if word.isupper():
            wordAllCaps = True
        #change, for example 'THE' to 'The' (and 'The' to 'The' but hey)
        if word[0].isupper():
            word = word.capitalize()
        #if the word is more than 3 chars
        if len(word) > 3:
            #and if the word as a single quote as the second char
            if word[1] == "'":
                #capitialize the third char in the word so "L'oréal" becomes "L'Oréal"
                word = ''.join([word[:2], word[2].upper(), word[2 + 1:]])
        #if the current word hasn't been seen before
        if word not in seen:
            #add it to seen
            seen.add(word)
            #if the word was originally all caps (like 'FOOBAR' but currently 'Foobar') change it back
            if wordAllCaps:
                word = word.upper()
            #add word to the output string
            output.append(word)     
        
    #return the list of words joined with spaces
    return ' '.join(output)

df['Name2'] = df['Name']
# df['Name2'] = df['Name2'].apply(unidecode.unidecode)
df['Name2'] = df.apply(lambda x: dedupString(x['Name2']), axis=1)
df['Name2'] = df['Name2'].str.replace(' , ', ', ', regex=False)

print(df)
```

**Outputs:**

```
                                                Name  \
0  LOVABLE Lovable Period Panties Slip da Ciclo M...   
1  Laessig LÄSSIG Set di Cucchiaio per bambini 4 ...   
2  Béaba BÉABA, Set di 6 Contenitori per la Pappa...   
3  L´Occitane L'OCCITANE - CREMA MANI NUTRIENTE A...   

                                               Name2  
0  LOVABLE Period Panties Slip da Ciclo Mestruale...  
1  Laessig LÄSSIG Set di Cucchiaio per bambini 4 ...  
2  Béaba, Set di 6 Contenitori per la Pappa Svezz...  
3  L'Occitane - CREMA MANI NUTRIENTE AL BURRO DI ...
```

**Note:**

- `LOVABLE Lovable` becomes `LOVABLE` as the first word is retained.  Similarly `Béaba BÉABA,` becomes `Béaba,` as the punctuation moves over to join the original first word.
- If you are happy to overwrite the existing column change `df['Name2'] =` to `df['Name'] =` in the code above.  I recommend checking/ sampling the output before removing the original column of strings.
- I've commented out a couple of lines (3 and 59) that could remove unicode (untested).  I've left it out for now but if required it's there.  When checking on the larger dataset you can see if unicode chars cause a problem (e.g., a string like `façade Facade` - match as duplicate or not is the question there.  Either swap out the unicode before removing duplicates (uncomment lines 3 and 59 and try it) or leave as is.

This works for the strings given.  Do note the comment in the code if characters disappear (as the dataset grows you may need to alter the regex)...

```
#split the strings inc. punctuation.  If ticks and dashes etc. go missing from the output
#add them to the end of the second square brackets below.  Example -> [.,!?;-HERE]
l = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;-]", s)
```

---

**Additional:**

If your expected output is that `Laessig LÄSSIG` becomes `Laessig` try:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import unidecode

data = {'Name': ["LOVABLE Lovable Period Panties Slip da Ciclo Mestruale Flusso Medio (Pacco da 2) Donna", 
                 "Laessig LÄSSIG Set di Cucchiaio per bambini 4 pezzi Uni menta/mirtillo",
             "Béaba BÉABA, Set di 6 Contenitori per la Pappa per Svezzamento Bebè in Silicone",
             "L´Occitane L'OCCITANE - CREMA MANI NUTRIENTE AL BURRO DI KARITÈ PER PELLI SECCHE 150ML"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

swaps = {"ä":"ae", 
         #"ö":"oe", 
         "ü":"ue", 
         "Ä":"Ae", 
         #"Ö":"Oe", 
         "Ü":"Ue", 
         "ß":"ss"}

def toASCII(s):
    '''
    Input is a string; 
    - if the string contains any char in the keys of 'swaps' replace that char
    - sets words that are ALL CAPS to All Caps for consistent output
    '''
    #if the string has a char that is in the keys of 'swaps'
    if any(e in swaps.keys() for e in s):
        #for each word
        for w in s.split():
            #if the word is ALL CAPS
            if w.isupper():
                #make it All Caps
                s = s.replace(w, w.capitalize())
            
            #replace, for example 'ä' with 'ae'
            for w, l in swaps.items():
                s = s.replace(w, l)
    return s

def dedupString(s):
    '''
    Given a string 's' it processes the string and returns a string with duplicated words removed.
    - replaces acute accent with single quote
    - split string inc. punctuation to list
    - sets 'ALL CAPS' words to 'All Caps' words (only during processing)
    - loops through list and removes duplicates
    - if word has a uppercase in the third char (like L'Oréal) reinstates that
    - deduplicates the list and returns the list joined with a " "
    '''

    #replace acute accent (´) with a single quote (')
    s = s.replace("´", "'")
    #split the string inc. punctuation.  If ticks and dashes etc. go missing from the output
    #add them to the end of the second square brackets below.  Example -> [.,!?;-HERE]
    l = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;-]", s)
    output = []
    seen = set()
    #loop through the words
    for word in l:
        wordAllCaps = False
        #if word is all caps record it
        if word.isupper():
            wordAllCaps = True
        #change, for example 'THE' to 'The' (and 'The' to 'The' but hey)
        if word[0].isupper():
            word = word.capitalize()
        #if the word is more than 3 chars
        if len(word) > 3:
            #and if the word as a single quote as the second char
            if word[1] == "'":
                #capitialize the third char in the word so "L'oréal" becomes "L'Oréal"
                word = ''.join([word[:2], word[2].upper(), word[2 + 1:]])
        #if the current word hasn't been seen before
        if word not in seen:
            #add it to seen
            seen.add(word)
            #if the word was originally all caps (like 'FOOBAR' but currently 'Foobar') change it back
            if wordAllCaps:
                word = word.upper()
            #add word to the output string
            output.append(word)     
        
    #return the list of words joined with spaces
    return ' '.join(output)

df['Name2'] = df['Name']
df['Name2'] = df.apply(lambda x: toASCII(x['Name2']), axis=1)
df['Name2'] = df['Name2'].apply(unidecode.unidecode)
df['Name2'] = df.apply(lambda x: dedupString(x['Name2']), axis=1)
df['Name2'] = df['Name2'].str.replace(' , ', ', ', regex=False)

print(df)
```

**Outputs:**

```
                                            Name  \
0  LOVABLE Lovable Period Panties Slip da Ciclo M...   
1  Laessig LÄSSIG Set di Cucchiaio per bambini 4 ...   
2  Béaba BÉABA, Set di 6 Contenitori per la Pappa...   
3  L´Occitane L'OCCITANE - CREMA MANI NUTRIENTE A...   

                                               Name2  
0  LOVABLE Period Panties Slip da Ciclo Mestruale...  
1  Laessig Set di Cucchiaio per bambini 4 pezzi U...  
2  Beaba, Set di 6 Contenitori per la Pappa Svezz...  
3  L'Occitane - CREMA MANI NUTRIENTE AL BURRO DI ...
```

Obviously with a larger dataset you'll have to see if you're happy with the `swaps` dictionary.  I've commented out a few things because, for example you may not want words like `Björn` (if present in the larger set) converted etc.